# HSQLDB: count(*) returns a decimal

Tags: java, sql, jpa, db2, hsqldb

I m using hsqldb in memory to execute JUnit Tests, to test data access objects.

In the DAO, i use the JPA Entity Manager to launch the following native SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AAA
```

The code looks like the following:

```
final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AAA");
return (Integer) query.getSingleResult() == 0;
```

The return statement let me check if i have a count equal to 0.
It works fine in production environment (DB2 is used).

But in our test env, with the hsqldb in memory, it fails because the query does not return an Integer or an int, but returns a `BigDecimal` (the cast fails).

HsqlDB 2.3.0 is used.
It worked fine before, with the 1.8 version of hsqldb.

Do you know why this problem occurs ? And how can i make the `count(*)` returning an integer ?

I would like, as much as possible, let the production code unchanged. Cause I know already that I can solve this problem with a sql cast, but this is not ideal in my point of view:

```
SELECT cast(COUNT(*) as int) FROM AAA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Java code to be platform independent. Cast the return value to Number and use getLong() instead of comparing an Integer.

HSQLDB actually returns a Long, not a BigDecimal